# Primeng p-table re-order items in virtualscrolling by fast scrolling

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

If you go to the demo page of virtual scrolling for [p-table](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/virtualscroll) and scroll to the end of the table and scroll **quickly** back up a little and then all the way back down again, you see the **last item** changes now and then. How to avoid this? any help would be appreciated!

as you see below, first the last item is "Renault Red", but after scrolling quickly up and then quickly down will show the last item as "Volvo Blue". Fast scrolling can be done with the free spin mode in Logitech mouselike MX Master.

[image]

Comment: I couldn't reproduced :/

Comment: I added a gif to show the problem better. I hope it helps!